# Adding numbers from a string without using split Java

Tags: java, function, split

I want to add the numbers from a user input, String. I know I can do it by using split function like this:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class MyClass{
    public static void main(String[] args){
        String[] Numbers = in.nextLine().split(" ");
        int sum = 0;
        for (String s : Numbers) {
            sum += Integer.parseInt(s);
        }
    }
}
```

Lets assume that the user input is: "1 2 3 4 5" the sum will be sum=15.

Ok, now I want to do it but without using arrays and the split().

A friend told me about using Scanner.hasNext() Method, but I cannot make it work

Comment: "cannot make it work": what did you try, and in what way(s) did it fail?

Comment: A little nitpicking: You might want to write variable names in lower case to make it easier to discern them from class names. `Numbers` -> `numbers`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class MyClass{
    public static void main(String[] args){
        int sum = 0;
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        while (in.hasNextInt()){
            sum += in.nextInt();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You also forgot to construct the scanner. `Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);`

Comment: @ccarton sorry have copied OP's code. Have changed it now.

Comment: a good idea would also be to specify a delimiter for the Scanner e.g. space like in OP's case: `.useDelimiter("\\s*");` because I think that was the base of OP's gripe with using the `.split(" ")`